# How do I clear a text field which is defined with in a div?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

For the html:

```
<div class="controls"> 
  <input type="text" id="13796781312861791131776">
```

I tried the following to clear the text field:

```
@browser.div(:class => /controls/).text_field(:topics_text_field, id:'13796781312861791131776').clear
```

Which gave the the following error:

```
expected one of [String, Regexp], got {:id=>"13796781312861791131776"}:Hash (TypeError)
```

Note: I am using Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how you're defining the attributes of the text field.

You are basically telling Watir that your text field can be identified by the Hash key/value pair of

`:topics_text_field => :id=> '13796781312861791131776'`

Watir doesn't know what to do with this (understandably, because that is a nonsensical key/value pair), so it throws an error telling you that you gave it something it didn't expect.

I would give you advice about exactly how to define it correctly, but you didn't include any of the HTML for the page containing this div and text field.

Comment: Html was provided, but not visible due to not being formatted as code. I updated the question so you can see the html.

Comment: /code I tried@browser.element(:css,'div[data-gd-attribute="topics"] input') & it did the job for me.

Comment: @Vamsi, your code would make better use of the Watir API if you did `@browser.div(:data_gd_attribute => 'topics').text_field` (assuming that the input is a text field).

Comment: @JustinKo I used the code you mentioned and I get the following 
/code 
undefined method `text_field' for #<Proc:0x007f9e54f4f818> (NoMethodError)
but if I use css and input it works , What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: @vamsi, are you sure you were using the same code? I do not see why the `div` method would return a proc. It should always return a div element (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: @JustinKo sorry about the delayed response but yes, I used the exact code that you mentioned.

Comment: @Vamsi, I tried the code and it seems to work fine. I would suggest you create a new question with a piece of html and code that can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
@browser.div(:class => /controls/).text_field(:id, "13796781312861791131776").clear
```

work?

Sorry, I couldn't include the topics_text_field part since you didn't include that in the html.